# List Doesn't Print (PIL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I wrote a very simple program, and something that has no reason for it not to work.  It isn't working. This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("0.png", 'r')

width, height = image.size
data = list(image.getdata()))
print(data)
```

The data never prints. No errors occur; nothing happens.

I have tried putting a print statement in between the `getdata()` command and `print(data)` command. The string prints, but the list still doesn't.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do the width and height print?

Comment: @PaulH yes. Width + height print.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? Run your script with `python -m pdb your_script.py` and step through to the line which gets you the data. You can inspect the variable / behaviour from there. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html for usage details for pdb.

Comment: @viraptor I tried that when printing random things every time a line goes. Everything works as expected up to the one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line: `data = list(image.getdata()))` you have one `)` too many.

For some reason this doesn't work when running through the IDLE, however if you run this through a terminal it will start printing the values.

I am guessing that PIL requires some function that is provided by the terminal and since the IDLE is not actually a terminal it cannot execute.

You may also want to add a `input()` to the end of your script to prevent the window from closing.